# Create File CentOs

Tags: java, linux, file, apache-spark, centos

I want to create a file in CentOs. When I use `File file=new File("path/file.txt")`, it creates a directory.

> FileNotFound:/temp/myfile.parquet Is a directory

When I create a file manually, so that it overwrites the existing file, it shows the following error and the file is empty.

> file:/temp/myfile.parquet already exists.; 2020-02-28 11:18:00.505
>   ERROR 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.gehc.odp.util.JsonToParquetConverter
>   : sparkcontext close

Comment: It will create a directory not a file as you specified.

Comment: `new File(String path)` doesn't create anything on the filesystem and wouldn't raise the `FileNotFound:/temp/myfile.parquet Is a directory` error

Comment: I created file using file.createnewfile(), now spark is unable to write . It says path already exists-                                                                                        Stack Trace: {}org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path file:/temp/myfile.parquet already exists.;
2020-02-28 14:04:08.072 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] c.gehc.odp.util.JsonToParquetConverter   : sparkcontext close